# Run C# WPF application with uiAccess = true in manifest at startup

Tags: c#, windows, scheduled-tasks

The application needs to stay on top of metro, hence the need for the `uiAccess` flag. This is a recent change in the application. In the previous version, where the `uiAccess` flag was not set, we could set the application to run on user access using this scheduled task:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<Task version="1.2" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windows/2004/02/mit/task">
  <RegistrationInfo>
    <Date>2014-04-23T11:31:11.9188616</Date>
    <Author>MU15\Utente</Author>
  </RegistrationInfo>
  <Triggers>
    <LogonTrigger>
      <Enabled>true</Enabled>
    </LogonTrigger>
  </Triggers>
  <Principals>
    <Principal id="Author">
      <UserId>MU15\Utente</UserId>
      <LogonType>InteractiveToken</LogonType>
      <RunLevel>HighestAvailable</RunLevel>
    </Principal>
  </Principals>
  <Settings>
    <MultipleInstancesPolicy>IgnoreNew</MultipleInstancesPolicy>
    <DisallowStartIfOnBatteries>false</DisallowStartIfOnBatteries>
    <StopIfGoingOnBatteries>false</StopIfGoingOnBatteries>
    <AllowHardTerminate>false</AllowHardTerminate>
    <StartWhenAvailable>true</StartWhenAvailable>
    <RunOnlyIfNetworkAvailable>false</RunOnlyIfNetworkAvailable>
    <IdleSettings>
      <StopOnIdleEnd>false</StopOnIdleEnd>
      <RestartOnIdle>false</RestartOnIdle>
    </IdleSettings>
    <AllowStartOnDemand>true</AllowStartOnDemand>
    <Enabled>true</Enabled>
    <Hidden>false</Hidden>
    <RunOnlyIfIdle>false</RunOnlyIfIdle>
    <WakeToRun>false</WakeToRun>
    <ExecutionTimeLimit>PT0S</ExecutionTimeLimit>
    <Priority>7</Priority>
    <RestartOnFailure>
      <Interval>PT1M</Interval>
      <Count>3</Count>
    </RestartOnFailure>
  </Settings>
  <Actions Context="Author">
    <Exec>
      <Command>"C:\Program Files (x86)\path\to\application.exe"</Command>
    </Exec>
  </Actions>
</Task>
```

We recently added the following application manifest:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<assembly manifestVersion="1.0" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <assemblyIdentity version="1.0.0.0" name="MyApplication.app" />
  <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2">
    <security>
      <requestedPrivileges xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
        <requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="true" />
      </requestedPrivileges>
      <applicationRequestMinimum>
        <defaultAssemblyRequest permissionSetReference="Custom" />
        <PermissionSet ID="Custom" SameSite="site" Unrestricted="true" />
      </applicationRequestMinimum>
    </security>
  </trustInfo>
  <compatibility xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:compatibility.v1">
    <application>
    </application>
  </compatibility>
</assembly>
```

The scheduled task now fails with error 0x800702e4: the requested operation requires elevation.

We tried putting a shortcut in `%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`, with no success.

Is there a way to run an application with the `uiAccess` flag set?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure so posting as a comment, but try setting `"If the task is already running (blabla)"` to `"Stop the existing instance"` on the Task Scheduler. This **should** (in theory) make it use `ShellExecuteEx` instead of `CreateProcess`, which is needed when you require elevation in the application manifest. I don't really have time to test it, hence a comment.

Comment: (that should be `<MultipleInstancesPolicy>StopExisting</MultipleInstancesPolicy>`, by the way)

Comment: It worked! Thanks a lot, post it as an answer and I will accept it :-)

Comment: There you go. Glad it worked

Comment: @ale were you able to find a solution for Win10?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the Task Scheduler uses by default `CreateProcess`, which won't work for running processes with a manifest that requires elevation: you'd need to use `ShellExecuteEx` for that.

There are probably other ways to do this, but at least one of them, with the task scheduler, is configure the task to stop other existing instances if the task is already running.

Via the GUI: `Settings -> "If task is already running (etc.)"`, set to `"Stop the existing instance"`, or in the XML:

```xml
<MultipleInstancesPolicy>StopExisting</MultipleInstancesPolicy>
```

Comment: We tried this solution on a Windows 10 machine and it's not working (we are getting the same  0x800702e4 error), do you happen to have some clue on this issue too?

Comment: @ale no, not really... I use a Windows 10 box however I don't have any application with a `uiAccess=true` manifest to try on... might give it a shot at a later date, I'm currently doing other stuff and can't test